# Sublime Text 3047 UI is so big

Tags: sublimetext3

The UI size of Sublime Text 3047 (tabs, state and search bars) are too big. Other versions on ST3, as well as ST, are normal. Is there anything we can do to make it smaller?

[image]

The left side is Sublime Text 3.

2 days later, I found out that this problem is caused by High DPI of system. If I change my system CPI to 1, everything looks ok.

Sublime Text 3 is start to having high DPI support but I guess it is not ready yet! In the sublime Text console shows the DPI is 1.25. **Can we force this DPI to 1?**

```
DPI scale: 1.25 
startup, version: 3047 windows x64 channel: stable
```

Answer (score 26):

Maybe it's a bit late, but apparently there is a hidden option (it doesn't appear anywhere) that allows you to set the DPI.

You have to write this in your user preferences and restart Sublime Text.

```
"dpi_scale": 1.0
```

I was having the same issue and I just discovered it by chance.

Tested with Sublime Text 3 Build 3061.

Comment: Most of the other settings update on the fly and the restart took me for a spin. Looks great. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I finally got Sublime 3 looking good in my KDE system (with custom DPI of 112) by adding this to my Sublime settings: "dpi_scale": 1.6,

Comment: This seems to have changed to `ui_scale` in ST4